# How to get full path of a file with FileUpload Control?

Tags: javascript

i am using FileUpload Control in my application to upload user information.when i used javascript to get the value of fileupload Control it give only the name of file in mozilla while in IE it's give the whole path with file name. And i want the file name with whole path.
mozilla Result - `user.doc`
IE Result - `/usr/local/user.doc` (which i want)

```
<input type="file" id="myFile" />
<input type="button" onclick="getFile();" />

<script type="text/javascript">

function getFile() {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById("myFile").value;
    alert(fileInput);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Modern browsers do not give this information since it is considered insecure.  There is no consistent way to this with HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: Yes.  It would be a breach of privacy for browsers to allow this because it would reveal information about the directory structure, including directory names, on the user's computer.  It's a bit disconcerting that this is possible in IE.

Comment: It's very predictable that this is possible in IE, isn't it?